# Why is my OpenGL renderer shows my CPU?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, gpu, opengl

From What I've searched, my openGL renderer should show my discrete GPU but strangely, it shows my integrated GPU.

Here is my `lspci | grep -E "VGA|Display"`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev c3)
```

and my `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
```

I have an Ubuntu 18.04

Running on Inspiron 15 5567 16GB ram which has Radeon R7 M440

I've also tried switcharoo with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set DRI_PRIME value before running the programs. 
Example
`DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL`
This is assumming you already set the proper provider
related article : [PRIME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME)